# passing values of IO Process to another class in real time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, static, inputstream

I have a basic question for which I need a some clarification in it's use.
So if I have one class in Java say `IOReadWrite.java`, where I do some IO read/write. So that it may have an always connected loop something like:

```
while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null){
     //incoming data
}
```

Now I have another class, call it `FrontEnd.java` where I am supposed to display the results coming in real time from `IOReadWrite.java` Class. Normally what is happening is that if I call the method of IO class, I can not get result unless the whole IO Operation is finished and I have to wait.

However what I want is to be able to get those results in real time, so that as soon as there is something on input Stream, I can get it in my FrontEnd Class to do whatever I want to do with it.

One idea I have come up with is using a static String variable in IOReadWrite.java and write a method which simply returns the value of this variable and I can poll this function from main class. But I'm pretty sure this is a very bad approach.

Can you suggest what is the proper way of getting such information in real time?

Comment: `IOReadWrite`'s operation does run in a separate thread, right? If it doesn't, you will block no matter what. If it does, you just need to share (and synchronize) some data structure between the threads (even just a String).

Comment: @Viruzzo, thanks yes it is in another thread, problem is this is a general method which can be used by any other class which imports this library, so in that case i can not call outside functions from this class, rahter i just need to provide a single front end for the users who are going to use it's functionality. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
FrontEnd frontEnd = 
while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null){
     //incoming data

     // notify immediately.
     frontEnd.displayLine(line);
}
```

What displayLine does depends on your implementation of that class.  Can you give any more details of that the class does with the information?

Something it could do is

```
private final BlockingQueue<String> linesQueue = ...

public void displayLine(String line) {
     linesQueue.add(line);
}

// somewhere else, in another thread.
String line = linesQueue.take(); // wait for a line.

String line = linesQueue.poll(); // get the next or null
```

Comment: Oh this background logger thread is really what i was looking for, thanks it will solve my problem!!

Comment: @Johnydep either use a singleton (if you have only one frontend or reading thread) or pass the frontend to the reading thread as a parameter before starting it.